# C++ remove function: doesn't accept a string variable

Tags: c++

Two examples:
When I do:

```
string filename = "apple";
remove(filename+".txt");
```

it produces an error, yet

```
string filename = "apple";
remove("apple.txt");
```

doesn't. Why is it not working and why can I use, for example the following:

```
string filename = "apple";
ifstream apple (filename+".txt");
```

Comment: What type is `filename`?

Comment: Make `filename` a `std::string`.

Comment: What is `remove`? [This function?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) You realize that function takes a `const char*`, yeah? Try `remove((filename+".txt").c_str())` (assuming `filename` is a `std::string`)

Comment: Is `filename` a `char*` or `std::string`?

Comment: Concatenating the two strings should work fine, unless filename is not the a `const char*`

Comment: What about it doesn't work, does the program run?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the standard C++ library doesn't provide overloads of standard C library functions to work with `std::string` as well as `char const*`.

Comment: "It doesn't work" + no indication what `filename` is = closevote

Comment: "the string filename is always equal to "apple"."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, `filename` is of type `std::string`, I can think of couple of ways of resolving your problem.

1. Use the suggestion by @Cornstalks in the comments:

   ```
   remove((filename+".txt").c_str());
   ```
2. Create a helper function in your application's namespace and use it.

   ```
   namespace myapp
   {
       int remove(std::string const& filename)
       {
           return std::remove(filename.c_str());
       }
   }

   myapp::remove(filename+".txt");
   ```

Comment: "Vote up requires 15 reputation". Thanks. The first one worked.

Comment: No worries. If my answer helps you with resolving your problem, then it's all good.